# why mysql order by keyword is not working as expected with GROUP by keyword?

Tags: php, mysql

I have following tables with columns :

1) users

```
user_id  username
```

2) projects

```
p_id   p_name
```

3) project_status

```
psdi    p_id    cdid   cid   sid  short_list   res_sent   status_date
```

4) company

```
cid   company_name
```

5) status

```
sid    status_name    status_order    is_cv_sent
```

6) projects_log

```
pl_id   cdid    project_name     p_id   user_id   status   date_time
```

Now, in this `projects_log` table there are same `p_id` value exist.

**I want to show all unique `p_id` with latest `date_time`.** as DESC order..

I am using following query but can't get the results. It's not showing me all unique `p_id` as `date_time` DESC order :(

```
$get_log = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT 
    pl.*, 
    u.username, 
    p.p_name, 
    c.company_name, 
    s.status_name, 
    ps.* 
    FROM projects_log AS pl 
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id =  pl.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN projects AS p ON p.p_id = pl.p_id     
    LEFT JOIN project_status AS ps ON ps.p_id = pl.p_id 
    LEFT JOIN company AS c ON c.cid = ps.cid 
    LEFT JOIN status AS s ON s.sid = ps.sid 
    WHERE pl.cdid = '$cdid' GROUP BY pl.p_id
    ORDER BY pl.pl_id DESC ");
```

**Update :**

Now using this query but showing me error message :

> mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean
>   given

```
$get_log = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
    pl.*, 
    u.username, 
    p.p_name, 
    c.company_name, 
    s.status_name, 
    ps.* 
    FROM projects_log AS pl 
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id =  pl.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN projects AS p ON p.p_id = pl.p_id     
    LEFT JOIN project_status AS ps ON ps.p_id = pl.p_id 
    LEFT JOIN company AS c ON c.cid = ps.cid 
    LEFT JOIN status AS s ON s.sid = ps.sid 
    WHERE pl.cdid = '$cdid' 
    ORDER BY pl.pl_id DESC )
    as new_tab
    GROUP BY new_tab.p_id ");
```

**Updated Error Message :**

> Error: Duplicate column name 'p_id' Warning: mysqli_fetch_array()
>   expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\frontend\getContactDetails.php on line 648

Answer (score 1):

Try this query :-

```
Select * from (
SELECT
    pl.pl_id,pl.cdid,pl.project_name,pl.p_id,pl.user_id,pl.status,pl.date_time,
    ps.psid,ps.cid,ps.sid,ps.short_list,ps.res_sent,ps.status_date,  
    u.username, 
    p.p_name, 
    c.company_name, 
    s.status_name, 
    pl.pl_id grp_use
    FROM projects_log AS pl 
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id =  pl.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN projects AS p ON p.p_id = pl.p_id     
    LEFT JOIN project_status AS ps ON ps.p_id = pl.p_id 
    LEFT JOIN company AS c ON c.cid = ps.cid 
    LEFT JOIN status AS s ON s.sid = ps.sid 
    WHERE pl.cdid = '$cdid' 
    ORDER BY pl.pl_id DESC
) as new_tab
GROUP BY new_tab.grp_use
```

Comment: I am trying with now.

Comment: It's showing me error. May be it's for comma or something else. Can you make it with my given style. I mean with variable and mysqli_query ?

Comment: Opps, I accidentally edited your answer. Actually what I am doing now is on updated section.

Comment: I have updated my question with what I am using now. Please check it

Comment: Can you tell me why it's showing me error message ?

Comment: It's showing me : Error: Duplicate column name 'p_id'

Comment: plz try this query @shibbirahmed

Comment: why not you edit your original answer so that I can understand better.

Comment: E.g : Error:
Notice: Undefined index: pl_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\frontend\getContactDetails.php on line 647

Notice: Undefined index: cdid in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\frontend\getContactDetails.php on line 648

Notice: Undefined index: p_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\frontend\getContactDetails.php on line 649

Comment: It's showing me lots of error message with unexpected result. E.g. It's showing all `p_id` etc...

Comment: It's not `psdi`. Its `psid` I fixed it but error message :  Duplicate column name 'cdid'

Comment: it's not grouping the result set. It's showing all with duplicate. It's should be unique AND latest one with date_time

Comment: can you create tables on sqlfiddle @shibbirahmed

Comment: I have given my table structure in the question

Comment: Any chance to fix it ?